# Restarting browser after every feature file cucumberjs

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, hook, cucumberjs

Currently we have an automation framework built using cucumberjs/protractor. As is now, all of our tests run in one browser instance.. this causes issues with our mocking system as it causes instabilities as more and more tests run. What is the easiest solution to make cucumberjs tests kick off a fresh browser instance at every new feature file? Would it include configuring the hooks.js?

Answer (score 0):

Create a before hook in your hooks.js:

```
this.Before(()=> {
  this.browser.restart();
})
```

http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.restart

Comment: what kind of syntax is that? This caused my broswer to restart before every scenario and I got an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'restart' of undefined

Comment: If you're referring to the `()=>` that is just an ecma6 fat arrow function. The `Before` is a cucumber before-hook. It's just an example. You can write the plumbing to restart after every file, rather than after every scenario, but the key is the `this.browser.restart()`, per protractor documentation

Comment: How can I specify hooks at the feature level? All examples are based around scenarios.. very little documentation on cucumberjs

Comment: You may be able to use the [before feature](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/735e42656031b1192c8c4444599a7fa23d5d9b58/src/runtime/features_runner_spec.js) hook. Otherwise, you may have to use tags.